# Creating Duplication constraint on mysql table

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have the following table, I am trying to create a constraint on the table that states that the `Ter_ID column` can have the same `Ter_ID` repeating however the corresponding `Status` cannot be the same at anytime, so if for example one is trying to update `Ter_ID 100P Status` from `U` to `A` it wouldn't go through seeing that there is already a row with the corresponding data.

```
Ter_ID  Status  Address
100P    A   Road1
100P    U   Road2
200R    A   Road2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a composed unique index using the two columns.

**Example:**

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`Ter_ID`, `Status`);
```

Be aware of the different NULL behaviour depending of the MySQL engine that you are using. From the official MySQL documentation:

> A **UNIQUE** index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. This constraint does not apply to **NULL** values except for the **BDB** storage engine. For other engines, a **UNIQUE** index permits multiple **NULL** values for columns that can contain **NULL**. If you specify a prefix value for a column in a **UNIQUE** index, the column values must be unique within the prefix.